# Did [cosmos] just get added as an [azure-cosmosdb] synomym?

Tags: discussion, bug, tags, search, tag-synonym-process

I typically check for [cosmos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cosmos) tag misuse every few days (sometimes people inadvertently add this tag to Cosmos DB questions). As of this morning, [cosmos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cosmos) is now pulling up [azure-cosmosdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb) questions. Interestingly, [cosmos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cosmos) and [azure-cosmosdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cosmosdb) don't show up as synonyms for each other.

Maybe someone added this as a synonym and it hasn't shown up yet in the web view? Maybe there's a glitch somewhere?

In any case... the two tags have nothing to do with each other, and any synonym-ness should be removed.

Comment: I think there's a problem with the search. I noticed, for example, that [[tag:ssms-19]] is giving back *very* wrong results earlier. I'd suggest rewording this as a [[meta-tag:bug]] report (feel free to use [[tag:ssms-19]] and [[tag:ssms-18]] as examples of wrong behaviour).

Comment: Looks like someone else has just raised the bug: ["Questions tagged X" shows questions without tag X](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419437/questions-tagged-x-shows-questions-without-tag-x)

Comment: If you search on the [synonym list page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms), the only synonym for that tag is [azure-documentdb]. You can see that same information on the [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/azure-cosmosdb/synonyms). I'm not sure why you'd get a redirect like that. I can't duplicate it, unfortunately

Comment: @Machavity - based on Larnu's comments, it seems like it might be a more generic issue and not specific to the tags I mentioned...

Comment: I strongly suspect it's the same issue now. Reported on MSE now. I think today's push broke the tag system somehow.