# "Questions tagged X" shows questions without tag X

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Stack Overflow shows me questions under [Questions tagged [electron]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/electron) which do not have that tag, nor do they seem to ever have had it, which should rule out caching as the culprit.

For example, I'm seeing the following questions:

- [Coulombs Law: Protons atract each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73108222/coulombs-law-protons-atract-each-other)
- [Cypress Docker: Chrome was not found on your sysyem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73107932/cypress-docker-chrome-was-not-found-on-your-sysyem)

Neither question has the [electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/electron) tag, but both have the word "electron" in their question body.

Is there some known behavior that causes these questions to appear on the "Questions tagged X" overview, while not really adding a visible tag?

Comment: Related: [Did \[cosmos\] just get added as an \[azure-cosmosdb\] synomym?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419436/did-cosmos-just-get-added-as-an-azure-cosmosdb-synomym). I also noticed odd behaviour on the [[tag:ssms-19]] and [[tag:ssms-18]] tags.

Comment: Looks like there's a bug on `/questions/tagged/[tag]` endpoint. Searching for `[tag] is:q` still works properly. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5belectron%5d%20is%3aq&searchOn=3

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing that too. Tagging for Dev review.

Comment: Also on MSE: [Questions not tagged \[x\] appear on the tag's question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380693/241919)

Comment: Same here, [tag:rdf] yields lots of unrelated results (but sometimes related, so this seems like a feature gone wrong).

Comment: Try [this meta search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/questions-tagged-x-shows-questions-without-tag-x) for "Questions tagged [questions-tagged-x-shows-questions-without-tag-x]". :)

Comment: This is happening for all tags. Most questions that show up are not related to the tag.

Comment: Also interesting to note that including multiple tags in the query also doesn't seem to suffer from this bug either; e.g. [`[cmd]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd) is broken but [`[cmd] [python]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd+python) isn't.

Comment: I'm no longer seeing this issue, maybe it's already been fixed.

Comment: Interesting. I could definitely reproduce the issue earlier (I saw that the [electron] tag page earlier was returning questions that didn’t have the tag), but it doesn't seem to be happening anymore. Glad it’s fixed itself, I guess... I suppose I'll mark it as [status-completed], since whatever the issue was seems to be resolved now.

Comment: @V2Blast This is definitely not resolved. I just had this problem with [tag:vulkan], [tag:directx], and [tag:direct3d], once I went to [tag:micro-optimization] it went away for all the tags I view. The problem also persisted through forced refreshes.

Comment: It looks like the devs have confirmed what was causing the issue, and will be deploying a fix soon. They'll post an answer once they've confirmed that the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 13):

Stack Overflow Developer responsible for this bug here! I've been investigating a different way to retrieve the Posts-associated-with-a-Tag data, starting with the Newest-sorted data and, unfortunately, when I turned it on for a short duration on the Stack Overflow site it exhibited an incorrect behaviour which I hadn't seen in the testing that I had performed locally and on other sites.

The new code is behind a feature flag and so can be toggled on or off easily, which explains why the bug appeared and then disappeared and then briefly came back.

I'm confident that it is now working correctly (following a code deployment yesterday) and the flag is enabled again here (meta) and on the Stack Overflow site - so those sites are using the new code.

Thanks for reporting this bug and please accept my apologies for the inconvenience!

Comment: Was the elasticsearch instance not enough to get this info? (AFAIK, it can return post that has a tag). Or is there another problem being solved?

Comment: Elastic is able to provide the list of posts that have the tag in question but it can't (so far as I understand) return the data needed to render the "Related Tags" component seen in the right hand column - and it was the code to retrieve that data which was causing too much load.

Comment: Is "related tags" something team specific? I don't see it in the public Q&A instance?

Comment: Or are you talking about the /tags route? That was... unexpected, considering that it's a many-to-many relationship in the DB already.

Comment: It's way down near the end of the page if you're on mobile, just above the Hot Network Questions section on the "tagged" page.

Comment: It this kind of experiment the cause of [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419792/)?

Comment: I suspect that the issue that @DiplomacyNotWar has linked has a different root cause. I'll be commenting on there if anyone wants more details.