# What broke tag filtering?

Tags: bug, status-completed, filtering, tag-filters

All questions appearing here are tagged Python, not C#.

[image]

On the first refresh, I got R questions, and on the second I got Python questions, but it seems to have resolved itself now. I'd be curious to hear from SE staff as to what caused it, though!

It has been suggested it might be related to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419437/questions-tagged-x-shows-questions-without-tag-x), which certainly seems a possibility.

Repro courtesy of [samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2777074) - Office questions under LaTeX:

[image: Repro]

Comment: No repro for me

Comment: @Nick I refreshed twice and the first time I got R questions, the second time I got Python questions, now I seem to get C# questions as expected. It seems like someone broke something ever so briefly.

Comment: I also noticed this glich recently. Several times.

Comment: Might be related to ["Questions tagged X" shows questions without tag X](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419437/questions-tagged-x-shows-questions-without-tag-x)

Comment: Repro - and the worst of it: one gets to see office questions in the latex tag -- that's torture! https://i.stack.imgur.com/myTku.png

Comment: Stack Developer here: there was a separate change deployed yesterday relating to tag list caching but I can't envisage how it could have caused this but I'll keep an eye on it. I can't deny that it seems suspicious, though! There was a deployment two hours ago that I'll look into as well in case that could have caused a temporary blip. I'm trying various things to reproduce on the live site and locally. I'll report back when progress is made.

Comment: I've got a hypothesis that I hope to confirm and roll out a fix for at the start of next week. In the meantime, I've disabled the new caching format so that this shouldn't be seen again.

Comment: We don't generally close fixed bug reports as not reproducible. That's what the [tag:status-completed] tag is for. I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stack Overflow developer here: I suspect that a deployment pushed out on Thursday introduced a bug as part of a change to the way in which this data is cached that meant that when the application was restarted (such as during subsequent deployments) there was a chance of cache key collisions that would result in incorrect data being displayed for a short period of time.

The new cache implementation was enabled on a site by site basis, depending upon a new site setting that we could enable or disable. So it was disabled when we saw this report.

A fix has now been made live and the setting re-enabled on this site (meta.stackoverflow.com) and on [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) - soon, it will be enabled across all sites.

Please accept my apologies for introducing this problem and thanks for reporting it! It must have been frustrating seeing the incorrect results and confusing that it was for short periods of time but potentially on multiple occasions (if it was happening for some data every time that the application was updated)! There are some important changes afoot with this technology internally but hopefully everything will be stable again now!

Comment: There isn't any need for apologies when done in a timely manner. We are at day 23 with [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380834/).