# Question tagged [x] don't return [x] tagged questions

Tags: bug, questions

Seems like a second iteration of [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419437/questions-tagged-x-shows-questions-without-tag-x)...

I navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript and alas, the questions don't even have a [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag:

[image: incorrect tags]

I opened the link in Incognito (Chrome 114) and it shows the same thing. The expected behavior would be that the questions are all tagged with the correct tag.

##### [Edit]

Seems like the issue just corrected itself, but apparently the bug's still existent.

Comment: I've definitely seen this before; its rare, but I've had it happen to me multiple times. You seemingly get results for a different tag (looks like `iterator` in OP's case). But a refresh moments later will correct itself.

Comment: Most likely some internet caching bugging out

Comment: I tried this (watched `javascript` sorted search by `newest`) as shown in the picture and I am getting the correct results. May it was a temporary thing or some issue at your end, or it's already fixed.

Comment: @user13267 yeah, it only occurred for about 3 minutes total, and during that time was reproducible even when not signed in.